# Having a problem figuring out how to get Ethernet interface info on Mac OS X using ioctl/SIOCGIFADDR/SIOCGIFCONF?

Tags: linux, macos, ethernet, ioctl

Are you having a problem figuring out how to get interface info on Mac OS X using ioctl/SIOCGIFADDR/SIOCGIFCONF?

I had a lot of trouble getting code that worked fine on Linux to work on Mac OS X today.

Answer (score 12):

Copy-paste to `main.c` and `gcc main.c && ./a.out` should work (lists all network interfaces, their ipv4/6 address, netmask and **MAC address** if associated):

Works fine on **Mac OSX** and **iOS iPad/iPhone**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  struct ifaddrs *if_addrs = NULL;
  struct ifaddrs *if_addr = NULL;
  void *tmp = NULL;
  char buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  if (0 == getifaddrs(&if_addrs)) {    
    for (if_addr = if_addrs; if_addr != NULL; if_addr = if_addr->ifa_next) {

      printf("name : %s\n", if_addr->ifa_name);

      // Address
      if (if_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        tmp = &((struct sockaddr_in *)if_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
      } else {
        tmp = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)if_addr->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr;
      }
      printf("addr : %s\n",
             inet_ntop(if_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family,
                       tmp,
                       buf,
                       sizeof(buf)));

      // Mask
      if (if_addr->ifa_netmask != NULL) {
        if (if_addr->ifa_netmask->sa_family == AF_INET) {
          tmp = &((struct sockaddr_in *)if_addr->ifa_netmask)->sin_addr;
        } else {
          tmp = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)if_addr->ifa_netmask)->sin6_addr;
        }
        printf("mask : %s\n",
               inet_ntop(if_addr->ifa_netmask->sa_family,
                         tmp,
                         buf,
                         sizeof(buf)));
      }

      // MAC address
      if (if_addr->ifa_addr != NULL && if_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK) {
        struct sockaddr_dl* sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)if_addr->ifa_addr;
        unsigned char mac[6];
        if (6 == sdl->sdl_alen) {
          memcpy(mac, LLADDR(sdl), sdl->sdl_alen);
          printf("mac  : %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
        }
      }

      printf("\n");
    }
    freeifaddrs(if_addrs);
    if_addrs = NULL;
  } else {
    printf("getifaddrs() failed with errno =  %i %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The mechanism to get MAC addresses is entirely different on BSD-derived OSes than on Linux. This includes OS X.

Here's code I use that works on Linux and OS X, and probably on the BSDs, too:

```
#if defined(HAVE_SIOCGIFHWADDR)
bool get_mac_address(char* mac_addr, const char* if_name = "eth0")
{
    struct ifreq ifinfo;
    strcpy(ifinfo.ifr_name, if_name);
    int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    int result = ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifinfo);
    close(sd);

    if ((result == 0) && (ifinfo.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family == 1)) {
        memcpy(mac_addr, ifinfo.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, IFHWADDRLEN);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
#elif defined(HAVE_GETIFADDRS)
bool get_mac_address(char* mac_addr, const char* if_name = "en0")
{
    ifaddrs* iflist;
    bool found = false;
    if (getifaddrs(&iflist) == 0) {
        for (ifaddrs* cur = iflist; cur; cur = cur->ifa_next) {
            if ((cur->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK) &&
                    (strcmp(cur->ifa_name, if_name) == 0) &&
                    cur->ifa_addr) {
                sockaddr_dl* sdl = (sockaddr_dl*)cur->ifa_addr;
                memcpy(mac_addr, LLADDR(sdl), sdl->sdl_alen);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        freeifaddrs(iflist);
    }
    return found;
}
#else
#   error no definition for get_mac_address() on this platform!
#endif
```

It's up to you to work out how to get the right `HAVE_*` macro defined for the platform. I happen to use autoconf for this, but you may have another way of dealing with platform differences.

Notice that the default interface name parameter for these functions is the default for the first Ethernet interface on Linux and OS X boxes. You may need to override this for other OSes, or pass another value if you're interested in the MAC address for a different interface.

Answer (score 2):

This thread matched my problem somewhat:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10935410&tstart=0

This thread helped a lot:

https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-hackers/2007-September/000767.html

because that thread eventually mentions that getifaddrs() should be used instead.  The man page on Ubuntu 10.04 had a great example of how to use getifaddrs and using it as a reference helped me figure out code that worked on both Mac and Linux.  I don't want anyone else to waste time on something so simple, so I'm posting and answering myself here.  Hoping that my post helps you...